# Giving users GRANT EXECUTE database permissions

Tags: mysql, sql, permissions

Are there any dangers to giving users GRANT EXECUTE permissions in MySQL? The intention is to limit them to running stored procedures only. I have not restricted the GRANT EXECUTE permissions to individual stored procedures however. Thanks.